# How to leave or silence a group ichat?

Tags: iphone, ichat, vibrate

I keep company with night owls. Also, I have an iPhone 4s. Oftentimes, my friends include me in group ichats that start at a reasonable hour, but continue into the middle of the night. Every time I get a group ichat, or any text, my phone vibrates. I want to keep it this way -- except for late night group chats.

Is there any way to mute or leave group ichats?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Do not disturb is a feature that isn't supported in iOS 5.

Comment: Good news is that this is a feature in iOS 6 - something you will likely see within a month (or two).

Comment: Ay thanks. But... there's no third party app? I gotta jailbreak?

Comment: There may be an option if you jailbreak it (I'm not familiar with what can be done with that), but the problem would come down to the sandboxing that Apple puts all iOS apps into. In general no app can control another app, or system function (again, there may be exceptions to this). So there won't be another app that can set do not disturb. I'm not aware of a messaging app that can do this built in either (but my knowledge of apps like that is limited).